# When I save my Render to PNG format some parts of render are totally black and white

Tags: transparency, color

[image: RENDER]I need help to find out what caused this problem, My particles in the background are totally colorful and correct in the viewport render and also the final render but after saving all of them are B&W but the rest of the picture is in color. How can I save the same thing I see?
[image: PNG]